# Segmentation-models-pytorch returns black image

Tags: pytorch, kaggle, image-segmentation

I tried to use Segmentation-models-pytorch first time by following guideline and using it on my task on kaggle(HuBMAP), here is link for official guide:
https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch/blob/master/examples/cars%20segmentation%20(camvid).ipynb

Everything is the same: model, loss, optimizer, TrainEpochs, Dataloaders. Only thing changed is CLASSES.

**PROBLEM:** If we do not use argmax, prediction every time is red square, and if we use it, image is just black (everything becomes 0).  best_model.predict(image) tensors have really small numbers: just 5-10 pixels on entire image are bigger than 0.001. Is something wrong with training, data or what?

Output code:

```
for image, _ in valid_loader:
  image = image.to(DEVICE)
  pr_mask = best_model.predict(image)
  pr_mask = torch.argmax(pr_mask, dim=1) # argmax here
  pr_mask = (pr_mask.squeeze().cpu().numpy().round())
  predictions.append(pr_mask)
```

Example of tensors:
tensor([[[[9.9973e-01, 9.9984e-01, 9.9990e-01,  ..., 9.9987e-01,
9.9976e-01, 9.9955e-01],
[9.9988e-01, 9.9994e-01, 9.9997e-01,  ..., 9.9995e-01,
9.9991e-01, 9.9981e-01],
[9.9994e-01, 9.9997e-01, 9.9999e-01,  ..., 9.9998e-01,
9.9996e-01, 9.9992e-01],

As I see, results on valid does not change at all, tested even on 50 epochs:

Epoch: 0
train: 100%|██████████| 184/184 [01:59<00:00, 1.53it/s, dice_loss - 0.1374, iou_score - 0.7633]

valid: 100%|██████████| 163/163 [00:07<00:00, 23.07it/s, dice_loss - 0.02045, iou_score - 0.9608]

Epoch: 1
train: 100%|██████████| 184/184 [01:52<00:00, 1.63it/s, dice_loss - 0.1279, iou_score - 0.777]

valid: 100%|██████████| 163/163 [00:07<00:00, 20.97it/s, dice_loss - 0.02045, iou_score - 0.9608]

Code, if need more information is needed:
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/hubmap-hacking-the-human-vasculature/discussion/419779

Example of train and valid data. Photos have same names.

[image]

If you need more, I am ready to answer your questions!